# Kubernetes Permission denied in container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ibm-cloud

My company bought a software we're trying to deploy on IBM cloud, using kubernetes and given private docker repository. Once deployed, there is always a Kubernetes error : "Back-off restarting failed container". So I read logs in order to understand why the container is restarting and here is the error :

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/yseop-log/yseop-manager.log (Permission denied)
```

So I deduced that I just had to change permissions in the Kubernetes file. Since I'm using a deployment, I tried the following initContainer :

```
initContainers:
    - name: permission-fix
      image: busybox
      command: ['sh', '-c']
      args: ['chmod -R 777 /var']
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/yseop-engine
          name: yseop-data
        - mountPath: /var/yseop-data/yseop-manager
          name: yseop-data
        - mountPath: /var/yseop-log
          name: yseop-data
```

This didn't worked because I'm not allowed to execute chmod on read-only folders as non root user.

So I tried remounting those volumes, but that also failed, because I'm not a root user.

I then found out about running as User and group. In order to find out which User and group I had to write in my security context, I read the dockerfile and here is the user and group :

```
 USER 1001:0
```

So I tought I could just write this in my deployment file :

```
  securityContext: 
      runAsUser: 1001  
      rusAsGroup: 0
```

Obvisouly, that didn't worked neither, because I'm not allowed to run as group 0

So I still don't know what to do in order to properly deploy this image. The image is working when doing a docker pull and exec on m computer, but it's not working on Kubernetes.

Here is my complete Volume file :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  annotations:
    ibm.io/auto-create-bucket: "true"
    ibm.io/auto-delete-bucket: "false"
    ibm.io/bucket: ""
    ibm.io/secret-name: "cos-write-access"
    ibm.io/endpoint: https://s3.eu-de.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud
  name: yseop-pvc
  namespace: ns
  labels:
    app: yseop-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: ibmc
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

And here is my full deployment file :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: yseop-manager
  namespace: ns
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: yseop-manager
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: yseop-manager
    spec:
      securityContext: 
          runAsUser: 1001  
          rusAsGroup: 0
      initContainers:
        - name: permission-fix
          image: busybox
          command: ['sh', '-c']
          args: ['chmod -R 777 /var']
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/yseop-engine
              name: yseop-data
            - mountPath: /var/yseop-data/yseop-manager
              name: yseop-data
            - mountPath: /var/yseop-log
              name: yseop-data
      containers:
        - name: yseop-manager
          image:IMAGE
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: SECURITY_USERS_DEFAULT_ENABLED
              value: "true"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/yseop-engine
              name: yseop-data
            - mountPath: /var/yseop-data/yseop-manager
              name: yseop-data
            - mountPath: /var/yseop-log
              name: yseop-data
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      volumes:
        - name: yseop-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: yseop-pvc
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: could you modify your busybox not to exit to early, login to it and check permissions you have?  Shall be ran as root. Do you have any issues for `yseop-engine` or `yseop-manager`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was not told by my company that we do have restrictives Pod Security Policies. Because of that, volumes are Read-only and there is no way I could have written anything in said volumes.

The solution is as follow :

```
      volumes:
    - name: yseop-data
      emptyDir: {}
```

Then, I have to specify a path in volumeMounts (Which was already done) and create a PVC, so my Data would be persistent.

Comment: Can you post your entire yaml file, i am facing same problem

Answer (score 7):

Can you please try including supplementary group ID in the security context like

```
SecurityContext:
   runAsUser: 1001  
   fsGroup: 2000
```

By Default **runAsGroup is 0 which is root**. Below link might give more insight about this.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/

Working Yaml Content

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: yseop-manager
  namespace: ns
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: yseop-manager
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: yseop-manager
    spec:
      securityContext: 
          fsGroup: 2000 
      initContainers:
        - name: permission-fix
          image: busybox
          command: ['sh', '-c']
          args: ['chown -R root:2000 /var']
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/yseop-engine
              name: yseop-data
            - mountPath: /var/yseop-data/yseop-manager
              name: yseop-data
            - mountPath: /var/yseop-log
              name: yseop-data
      containers:
        - name: yseop-manager
          image:IMAGE
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          securityContext:
             runAsUser: 1001
             runAsGroup: 2000
          env:
            - name: SECURITY_USERS_DEFAULT_ENABLED
              value: "true"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/yseop-engine
              name: yseop-data
            - mountPath: /var/yseop-data/yseop-manager
              name: yseop-data
            - mountPath: /var/yseop-log
              name: yseop-data
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      volumes:
        - name: yseop-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: yseop-pvc
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I tried with fsGroup = 1000 but it does not work, Initcontainer permission fix is always back-off restarting failed container. I tried to remove said initcontainer, so the pod was executed but I still have the permission denied error. That being said, the reason behind this back-off restarting is that chmod command fails on /var folder.

Comment: Can you try to execute the pod and traverse to the path and see the permission for that folder. **kubectl exec -it yseop-manager -- sh; check ls /var and ls /var/yseop-log** just to with what permission actually the folder structure has got.

Comment: Permissions for /var :`total 25 drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 5 07:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug  5 07:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug  5 07:28 run
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 27 19:19 spool
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 27 19:19 www
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 5 07:28 yseop-data
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root 0 Jan 1 1970 yseop-engine
drwxrwxr-x 1 root root 0 Jan 1 1970 yseop-log` And permissions for /var/yseop-log `total 5
drwxrwxr-x 1 root  root  0 Jan  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root  root  4096 Aug  5 07:28 ..`

Comment: I have edit the above answer and included the yaml file content which might work for you. Please do let me know if it works fine.

Comment: I'm now getting the follwing error : Error: container has runAsNonRoot and image will run as root. I went into logs and permission-fix failed, here is the log : Error from server (BadRequest): container "permission-fix" in pod "yseop-manager-f5b7f854c-26vcg" is waiting to start: CreateContainerConfigError

Comment: Please make sure the UID 1001 is available and also please include **runAsNonRoot: true in spec.containers.securityContext**. Mostly this error will come only when UID is not present but we can try enforcing to run as not root user by setting runAsNonRoot: true value,

Comment: So I managed to fix that. I was not told that my company put restrictive PSP, thus there is no way I would be able to directly write in volumes. However, I could just mount emptydir as volumes and then create a PVC that would store those data.